# Correlation between $\sqrt{1/10}$ and length of powers of integers.

Tags: proof-explanation, radicals, irrational-numbers

I'm searching information about this simple problem involving square roots and length of powers.
It's very simple but it seems interesting, at least for me.
I'm not a mathematician.

**Description**

By observing the sequence of all positive integers where the length of their square increments:

```
  1  4  10   32   100     317
  1 16 100 1024 10000  100489
```

We can see that it happens alternatively at powers of 10 and at some particular numbers.

This is the algorithm in [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) which I think it's self explanatory: *to_s* converts a number to string so that we can take its length, we print *x* if its power increases in length.

```
length = 0
temp   = 0
1.step{|x|
 if length < temp = (x**2).to_s.size
  length = temp 
  print"#{x}\n"
 end
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pyc1L70kQ8FWwYCrJDW3QEEBzDTUKy5JLaiuqajhUshMU4AqslEAK7FV0KjQ0jLS1CvJjy/WK86sSuVSUICbA1YCFCgoyswrUVKurqiNyVPiUkjNS@Gq/f8fAA)

If we discard powers of 10 we have those particular numbers:

```
4 32 317 3163 31623 316228 3162278 ..
```

It turns out that they are the sequence of digits of √(1/10)

```
31622776601683793319988935444327185337195551393252168268575048527925944386392382213442481083793002951873472841528400551485488560304538800146905195967001539033449216571792599406591501534741133394841240853169295770904715764610443692578790620378086099418283717115484063285529991185968245642033269616046913143361289497918902665295436126761787813500613881862785804636831349524780311437693346719738195131856784032312417954022183080458728446146002535775797028286440290244079778960345439891633492226526120677926516760..
```

The algorithm was improved to [this](https://tio.run/##DYm7CsMwDAB3fYVwlsSlIupc/0mm0gQMRoTIhdaPb3c13N1w1@f1GyMFhmLksIJamTTvZ23fBqhhnvXOi@eVSM0LHVHetYlNTM8S3FTF@0d3pLHsgB0whXJjwPOKktG@9k0cIPQx/g) giving a lot of digits with less resources.
It takes advantage of the observation that the next number differs only on the last two digits.
More precisely we can observe that after x we have a number in the range [ (x-1)10 .. x10 ).
But this is just a shortcut, let's stick to the original algorithm involving lengths.

One fellow noticed it was the digits of √(1/10) and explained me.. *"The length of integers increases at each power of 10. The length of squares of integers increases at (the ceiling of) each power of √10. Half of these powers are also powers of 10, while the other half are powers of 10 multiplied by √(1/10)"* which has same digits of √10 or √1.
That makes sense obviously but at the same time it seems like a different point of view. I can't find any proof, articles, anything about this.

So my question is: Does there exist any information about this simple concept?

I'm not a mathematician. As a side note it seems like we can compute square roots by observing the length of powers, in fact , we can also get the digits of [$\sqrt 2$](https://tio.run/##HcTLCoMwEEDR/XzFoBt1kTbjoxvzJ4VCMUIgRE1GSH18e5ReONev319KVj2Bb1IE1vN@xAPQjGh7VkURq4rKB5WCp08QwWwaEK3i@7M3jrN8j@fbZYDaDQBwwj8pGtmQrNuO6hfmYfGMlNIF) by inspecting the lengths of $(x^2)/2 $ or $(x^2)*5$ and similarly [√3](https://tio.run/##FYhBCsIwFAX37xSfdtN2EdOGki7MTQRBjBAIsSZfiLY9e4wDM4uJ79unFHgjwdVRJLbrtucd5B7kz2y6Lg/D1J9UL/h5TSK5rwWRN1y7Rhe4abd80CU0IBvuAA78GYVWk5zlIvWsqU2vyKTqL@UH) for example.

Comment: The Heron method should be efficient enough , if you do not need millions of digits. PARI/GP can easily calculate such numbers upto precisions of a few million digits if you actually need that.

Comment: Thanks @Peter , however is not that I need an alternative or better method, it's more about if this correlation between power length and radicals exits, it seems strange to me that I cannot find anything

Comment: You could just as easily describe it in terms of the digits of $\sqrt{10}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\times10$. Note also that, since $\sqrt{10}$ is irrational, the least square with a given even number of digits gives us an overestimate of $\sqrt{10}$. Therefore, a new digit will be incorrect until the next iteration, which reduces it by $1$ to the correct value. This is why the first few estimates are $4,\,32,\,317$ etc.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A017936

Comment: Thanks @lhf this is close to what I was searching for , i checked oeis but didn't find it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If $n$ is the number where the square change from having $k$ digits to $k+1$ digits then $(n-1)^2<10^k\le n^2$. So $n-1 < 10^{k/2}\le n$. If $k$ is even we have $n = 10^{k/2}$. If $k = 2m+1$ then $n-1 < 10^{m+1}\sqrt{1/10}< n$ which explains why the first digits of $n$ coincide with $\sqrt{1/10}$.

Comment: Thanks @jjagmath for giving a well defined proof